# Would a "Hit-List" Program be against the rules of GTA Online?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

Basically, I got an idea recently of creating a Python script that compares the players on the scoreboard with those in the list. If it happens that a player does exist on this Hit-List, you will be notified of their presence with a sound or desktop notification.

Wondering if the script like this, which doesn't modify the game in any way, apart from a macro that clicks "Z" 3 times to cycle through the scoreboard. All the idea is is to screengrab my own screen, seek players out, and return info if it so happens that the player in question exists.

It should in no way interfere with the game, and instead serves as a way to exact revenge on that tryhard that destroyed your cargo the night before, or the one that randomly targeted a group of low levels. It doesn't instantly kill someone, doesn't mod the game in any way. Just a notification.